# Cumulative Sum of Count

Tags: sql, count, sum

I would like to know whether a cumulative sum over a count is possible. An example I would like to work with is storms that affected the US this year. I would like a result-set that lists the months in 2014, along with the cumulative sum of storms that affected the US until that month. I am hoping to get something 3 columns - Month, NumberofStorms and CumulativeSum that look like this:

```
Month        NumberofStorms     CumulativeSum
-----------------------------------------------
Jan              2                   2
Feb              1                   3
Mar              1                   4
Apr              0                   4
May              0                   4
Jun              0                   4
Jul              0                   4
Aug              0                   4    
Sep              1                   5
Oct              3                   8
Nov              5                  13 
Dec              8                  21
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What database are you using?  What have you tried so far? Also, what does your source data look like?

Comment: This is not a real-life scenario but I am trying to create scenarios and answer them so I can learn analytic functions in sql. I would like to use my query on an Oracle db.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a window to a `SUM()`:

```
SELECT "Month"
      ,"NumberofStorms"
      ,SUM("NumberofStorms") OVER(ORDER BY "Month" ROWS BETWEEN unbounded preceding and current row) AS CumulativeSum
FROM Table1
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/98f83/5/0)

Note: The month is sorting alphabetically in the demo, didn't bother to input real dates since it's just a sample scenario.

Update:  Let's pretend the base table is just `Month` And `StormName`, you'll need a cte/subquery to first get a count that you can then use in the above running total:

```
SELECT "Month"
      ,"NumberofStorms"
      ,SUM("NumberofStorms") OVER(ORDER BY "Month" ROWS BETWEEN unbounded preceding and current row) AS CumulativeSum
FROM (SELECT "Month",COUNT("Name") AS "NumberofStorms"
      FROM Weather
      GROUP BY "Month"
      ) AS Sub
```

Comment: This is close to what I was expecting. But suppose I don't have the luxury of a column called "NumberofStorms". Suppose I have a table called Weather where there is a row created for each storm that occurs with the columns being, Month, Storm Name. In this case, I would need a count() wouldn't I?

Comment: Sure thing, you'd just use a cte/subquery to get a count, then do the running total. See update.

Answer (score 3):

You can do the cumulative sum without a subquery.  If `NumberOfStorms` is part of the original data:

```
SELECT "Month", "NumberofStorms",
       SUM(NumberofStorms) OVER (ORDER BY "Month" ROWS BETWEEN unbounded preceding and current row) AS CumulativeSum
FROM Weather
GROUP BY "Month", NumberOfStorms;
```

And, in many databases, the `row` clause is unnecessary, so the following should also work:

```
SELECT "Month", "NumberofStorms",
       SUM(NumberofStorms) OVER (ORDER BY "Month") as CumulativeSum
FROM Weather
GROUP BY "Month", NumberOfStorms;
```

If `NumberOfStorms` really comes from `count(*)`, then you would do:

```
SELECT "Month", count(*) as "NumberofStorms",
       SUM(count(*)) OVER (ORDER BY "Month") as CumulativeSum
FROM Weather
GROUP BY "Month";
```

At first, looking at the combination of cumulative sums and window/analytic functions looks a bit strange, you will quickly get used to it.

Comment: Don't you have to use group by month for count() so that you get the number of storms per month?

Comment: @Canzee . . . If you want the number of storms per month, then you would add `COUNT(*) as StormsPerMonth` to the `select` clause.  I see, this is explicitly part of the question.  I was focused on the cumulative part.  I'm confused is `NumberOfStorms` part of the original data?

Comment: The original table Weather has the columns Month and StormName only. There is no NumberofStorms in the table.

Comment: @Canzee . . . See the last query.