# Counting total of records by year

Tags: sql, linq, group-by, count

I want to count the amount of records by year, for each year. These records contain a datecreated field. But the count should include the previous years as well. So counting the years of 2013 should, include those lower years as well, but not yet of 2014 and higher.

Explanation preferably in linq.
 (sql is totally fine though)

I tried doing this by grouping by year, and then count for each year. Now only the previous years should be added, for each year.

I know this can be done with a lot where statements and selecting the results, but there should be a better way.

Comment: What SQL engine do you use?

Comment: When you say "previous years", do you mean only the previous year or all the previous years? I.e. if you're checking 2013, should it also include the records of 1985?

Comment: @MarkCiliaVincenti yes, 1985 should be included as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL you need *[SUM OVER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22108767/cumulative-sum-of-count)* but it is not supported by Linq. You can download yearly data and calculate the cumulative sums in memory.

```
var fromYear = 2010;
var toYear = 2019;
var yearlyData = Receipts.Where(x => x.DateCreated.Year >= fromYear & x.DateCreated.Year <= toYear)
                            .GroupBy(x => x.DateCreated.Year)
                            .Select(x => new { Year = x.Key, Count = x.Count() })
                            .ToList();

var result = Enumerable.Range(fromYear, toYear - fromYear)
                        .Select(year => new
                        {
                            Year = year,
                            CumulativeCount = yearlyData.Where(y => y.Year <= year).Sum(y => y.Count)
                        });
```

Also you can use an outer variable:

```
var fromYear = 2010;
var toYear = 2019;
var yearlyData = Receipts.Where(x => x.DateCreated.Year >= fromYear & x.DateCreated.Year <= toYear)
                            .GroupBy(x => x.DateCreated.Year)
                            .Select(x => new { Year = x.Key, Count = x.Count() })
                            .OrderBy(x => x.Year)
                            .ToList()
                            ;


var sum = 0;
var result = yearlyData.Select(x => new {x.Year, CumulativeSum =  sum += x.Count});
```

Comment: Something I did to improve your answer as well is adding: 
            var toYear = yearlyData.Max(x => x.Year);
            var fromYear = yearlyData.Min(x => x.Year);
And removing the where statement.

Answer (score 0):

Here's your query.

```
select count(1), year(created_date) from tableA 
where year(created_date) < 2014
group by year(created_date)
```

Comment: sorry for formulating the question badly, but this is not the answer I seek. I want every year. And every year, should contain the amount of records of all lower years.

Comment: mmm, but now it does only 2013. I want every year. So this is what I meant by using a lot of where statements.

Answer (score 0):

```
select sum(case when year(datecreated) <= 2013 then 1 else 0 end) as until_2013,
       sum(case when year(datecreated) <= 2014 then 1 else 0 end) as until_2014,
       sum(case when year(datecreated) <= 2015 then 1 else 0 end) as until_2015
from your_table
```

Comment: This works, but I like to have a solution where I don't have to define each year. Or is this unavoidable?

Comment: This got flagged as [low quality](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/24010015) for some reason. @Kamiccolo, code-only answers are rarely NAA, voting to delete is not appropriate